# Getting information from a JSON and saving in SQL Server using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, sql-server, rest, server

Getting information from a JSON and saving in SQL Server using JavaScript

I have this code, which returns the information I want and shows on the page.

Now I would need to save this information in a SQL Server database, how would that be possible?

This is very difficult for me since I have never worked with API, JSON or JavaScript before

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>     
        .bodyFrame {
            margin: 40px;
        }

        .headerLabel {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    </style>        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="bodyFrame">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">WIDS JSON Retrieval Example</h2>

        <button type="button" onclick="makeServiceCall()">Retrieve JSON Data</button>
        <br /><br />

        <label class="headerLabel">Programs</label>
        <ul id="programUL"></ul>
    <div>       
    <script>        
        function makeServiceCall() {                    
            var url = "http://widsservicedev.yaharasoftware.com/WidsService/JSON/GetPortagePrograms/?apikey=104043F0-9C24-4957-879D-046868973CC4&callback";

            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                //var myArray = [];
                //myArray[0] = data;
                parseProgramData(data, url);
            });                 
        }

        function parseProgramData(jsonData, url) {      

            $("#dataHeader").empty();
            $("#dataHeader").append('<b>' + url + '</b>');

            var programUL = document.getElementById("programUL");       

            for (var pgmIndex = 0; pgmIndex < jsonData.Programs.length; pgmIndex++) {                   
                var pgmLi = document.createElement("li");
                var program = jsonData.Programs[pgmIndex];
                var programInfoRevision = program.ProgramInfoRevisions[0];
                var numberTitle = programInfoRevision.ProgramNumber + " " + programInfoRevision.ProgramTitle;
                pgmLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(numberTitle));
                programUL.appendChild(pgmLi);                   

                var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
                pgmLi.appendChild(linebreak);

                var poLabel = document.createElement("label");
                poLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Program Outcomes"));
                poLabel.classList.add("headerLabel");                   
                pgmLi.appendChild(poLabel);                 

                var pgmOutcomeUL = document.createElement("UL");
                pgmLi.appendChild(pgmOutcomeUL);

                for (var poIndex = 0; poIndex < program.ProgramOutcomes.length; poIndex++) {                    
                    var poLi = document.createElement("li");
                    poLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(program.ProgramOutcomes[poIndex].Description));
                    pgmOutcomeUL.appendChild(poLi);
                }                                        
            }               
        }
    </script>           
</body> 
<footer>        
</footer>       
</html>
```

Comment: I think this question is too large to answer.  Getting JSON and storing into SQL requires a lot of moving parts.  You may want to look at some tutorials for each individual part of what you are trying to accomplish.  I would start with the back-end API to accept JSON and store into a database.

Comment: As @EMcG said you will need to research what solution you want as a server to save into a database. if you're looking for something free/opensource and lots of tutorials look at node.js with express.js plugin and using a library to talk to sql (there's different packages for PostgresSQL, MSQL, MySQL, MariaDb) that allow you to work with it and it all uses javascript so you wont need to learn a new language.